# htaccess to allow laravel site inside of wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, laravel

I have a wordpress site set up domian.com Now i made a folder called scheduler and installed a laravel application. Inside my laravel application i have a .htaccess with the following inside the scheduler folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* public/index.php [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

and the following htaccess is the main server folder where the wordpress site lives

```
 # BEGIN WordPress
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

 # END WordPress
```

what i need to happen is domian.com/scheduler or domain.com/scheduler/..... should point to the scheduler directory and run the laravel app what am i doing wrong what do i need to add into the main directory htaccess

Comment: Where does it redirect to now?

Comment: it goes to wp-login.php when i go to mydomain.com/scheduler

Comment: Is the .htaccess you've shared in the /scheduler folder?

Comment: updated the question to include both htaccess info one for the /scheduler folder and one in the main wordpress app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another rewrite rule with last `L` flag:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^scheduler($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

In cpanel or your hosting provider , go to domains, then click on create a new domain, after clicking on this in domain field write your subdomain and in document root field , write public html/scheduler , now you can use this subdomain to access our routes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).