# deploy Laravel project on subfolder in subdirectory

Tags: laravel, wordpress, deployment, subdirectory

i need to upload [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) project on sub folder in subdomain because there will be [wordpress](/questions/tagged/wordpress) website,
while i am searching i found that i can use [.htaccess](/questions/tagged/.htaccess), is there another way ? because i am new to laravel and no experience in [tag:.htaccess ]
--- subdmoain.com
--- public_html
--- subfolder
---laravel project

i tried using changing App_Url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just upload your Laravel files to `/public_html/subdomain/`
Then create a new file called `.htaccess` (yes, in the same subdomain folder) and then insert this code so it would start loading index.php from `/public_html/subdomain/public/` folder which exists in Laravel App:

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Save it. When you visit your subdomain URL now, the app should work.
If it throws any errors, then most likely your index.php paths aren't correct or you do not have `vendor/` folder.

Answer (score 1):

public_html
│
└───main_directory
│
└───sub_directory
│
└───laravel_project (Your Laravel project)

Here are the steps to deploy your Laravel project to a subfolder within a subdirectory:

Prepare your Laravel project:

Make sure your Laravel project is ready for deployment.
Ensure that the .htaccess file and configuration settings in Laravel (like APP_URL) are set correctly for this subdirectory.
Upload your Laravel project:

Upload the contents of your Laravel project to the laravel_project folder in your server's sub_directory.
Set up subfolder routing:

Create or modify the .htaccess file in the main_directory if it doesn't exist.
Add or modify the .htaccess file to redirect requests to your Laravel project's subfolder.
For Apache servers, the .htaccess file might look like this:

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /main_directory/sub_directory

# Redirect to the Laravel subfolder
RewriteRule ^laravel_project(/.*)?$ /main_directory/sub_directory/laravel_project/public/$1 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score -1):

.htaccess is of course the best way. But if you don't know how to do that, I think you can create a subdomain from your hosting provider (like hostinger, etc), and after that, you can upload it to that folder (the one with the subdomain). Ask the hosting provider contact person, they will gladly help you to set up the subdomain

Comment: i can't make a subdomain, is there any source i can make it work because i have no idea about .htaccess can you help with link or anything ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38685989/htaccess-to-allow-laravel-site-inside-of-wordpress 
maybe this one can help you, I never try it though

Comment: Thank you very much for helping, but i didn't try it because same as you i have no idea about .htaccess, i followed the other solution down